# Getting Error While trying to access it from Browser

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I had Uploaded image to server using PHP script , while i am tring to fetch it from browser 
I am getting error "This image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

But when i had downloaded it to local system it contain no error and displayed properly.

I have check folder permissions and image file permission too. all are set.

Below code is used for that purpose:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path."/".$filename)
```

**URL FOR REFERENCE:**

http://api.intofone.com/in2fone_new/fdepot/sharepics/Image25.png

What may be problem here?

Comment: How do you try to look at it in the browser? With a script or a direct link?

Comment: i have checked it form direct link..

Comment: Can you provide us with a url where we can see the broken image? Or show some more code?

Comment: ya sure.. http://api.intofone.com/in2fone_new/fdepot/sharepics/Image25.png

Answer (score 1):

I checked it in an editor and there is JFIF in it what means it is a JPEG and your extension is PNG